# I'm trying to change ImageView height as I scroll the page

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When i scroll down i want the height to decrease and the opposite. 
However, it seems that the whole coordinates  change even than i update only the height of the image frame.

```
if Double(scrollView.contentOffset.y) < 0 
{
    tmp = 0.0
} 
else if Double(scrollView.contentOffset.y) > maxImageY 
{
    tmp = maxImageY
}
else 
{
    tmp = Double(scrollView.contentOffset.y)
}

if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) 
{
    // move up
    print("up")
    newHeight = originalHigh + tmp
}
else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) 
{
    print("down")
    newHeight = originalHigh - tmp
}

vanishImageView(_x: originalImageX, _y: originalImageY, _width: width, _height: newHeight)

// vanishImageView
myImage.frame = CGRect(x:_x,y: _y, width: _width, height: _height)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add/minus diffrence between `self.lastContentOffset` and `scrollView.contentOffset.y` to `newHeight` instead of directly offset value. 
Or assign offset value to height instead of adding to current height.

Comment: you mean like this : newHeight = newHeight + Double(scrollView.contentOffset.y  - self.lastContentOffset)

Comment: That is depend on primary value assigned to `originalHigh` and `newHeight`.
I assumed `originalHigh` is imageview's current height. if `newHeight` primary assigned value is imageview's current height then this is what i mean.

Comment: doesn't work..  how does the scroller influence other objects? should the image be a child of the scroller? even though the imageview holds it's inital values it re locate its location on the page